# All ways to specify an iOS springboard icon for a website

Tags: ios, mobile-website

As per some google search results, [this for example](http://iboughtamac.com/2008/01/23/making-an-iphoneipod-touch-webclips-favicon/), there are at least two ways to specify an iOS springboard icon for a website (home screen favicon):

- Create a PNG image that is 57×57 pixels in size and save it as “apple-touch-icon.png” in the root of the website.
- Specify any image as the icon using html `<link>` tag like this: `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/whatever.jpg"/>`

Yahoo's mobile site, http://m.yahoo.com/, does display a favicon on my iphone. However, m.yahoo.com/apple-touch-icon.png is not available, and there is not such a `<link>` in its html source.

So are there any other ways to specify that icon?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good reference on the topic
http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/touch-icons